# UITableView header hides on beginUpdates() in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in a controller where I'm setting its `tableHeaderView` property in `viewDidLoad()`

```
let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderView") as! HeaderView
tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

All works well, until I call `tableView.beginUpdates()`/`tableView.endUpdates()` OR `tableView.reloadData()`. Header space is still there, but content goes blank.

What am I doing wrong ? Please suggest.

Comment: tableHeaderView hides when scrolling UITableView ? do you have UITableView inside scrollView ?

Comment: let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderView") as! HeaderView
 what does that mean you are dequeue cell as header view ?

Comment: You might have to use the delegate method `viewForHeaderInSection` to return the header dynamically

Comment: HeaderView class is a UIView? Maybe you should use the delegate method  viewForHeaderInSection do to return the head as an instance of the UIView class.

Comment: HeaderView is a UITableView prototype cell.

Comment: I don't want to use `viewForHeaderInSection`, I want is as a normal tableview cell, but dont want to put those conditional statements in tableview delegate methods to manage it.

Comment: It doesn't hide on scrolling. Works very fine until I reload tableView or call beginUpdates()

Comment: The header view is **not** a normal table view cell by definition.

Answer (score 1):

**== EDITED OCT 12, 2016 ==**

You should not dequeue the header view. Instead have a view property and assign that view to be the headerview for your tableview:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    // MARK: - Properties
    var headerView: UIView!

    // MARK: - Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        headerView = HeaderView()
        tableView.headerView = headerView
    }
}
```

**== ORIGINAL ANSWER - DOES NOT ADDRESS THE QUESTION ==**

You should not put the headerview on viewDidLoad. Instead create and return the header in the delegate (below code assumes you have one section).

IMPORTANT: You need to call `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier` NOT `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("HeaderView") as! HeaderView
    return headerView   
}
```

Comment: the question is about the `tableHeaderView` not the header for the sections

Comment: @oyalhi I needs dynamic header size and that's why i used custom tableview cell as header view. But its getting hide on beginUpdate(). Any solution ?